# React Redux: Warning: Unknown event handler property It will be ignored while in mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

While trying to create a simple redux flow, when trying to dispatch an event I get an error in the mapDispatchToProps saying that the function I declard: "Warning: Unknown event handler property `onProjectCreate`. It will be ignored."

I am using material UI with latest node/redux libraries.

> index.js file:

```
import reducer from "./store/reducer";
const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

const app = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
);
```

> reducer.js file

```
import * as actionTypes from "./actions";

const initialState = {
  projects: [
    {
      projectName: "test",
      description: "new description",
      members: "joni@gmail.com",
      projectType: "kanban"
    }
  ]
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.CREATE_PROJECT:
      console.log(action.title);
      return {
        ...state,
        projects: {
          ...state.projects
        }
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

> actions.js file

```
export const CREATE_PROJECT = 'CREATE_PROJECT';
```

> component where I use this

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as actionTypes from "../../../../store/actions";

/ simplified component
return (
    <Grid item xs={12}>
      <Button
        onClick={onProjectCreate}
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        className={classNames(classes.button, classes.paddingExtra)}
  >
    Create
  </Button>
</Grid>
)

const mapStateToProps = state => {
return {
    projects: state.projects
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onProjectCreate: () => dispatch({ type: actionTypes.CREATE_PROJECT })
  };
};

export default connect(
   mapStateToProps,
   mapDispatchToProps
)(withStyles(styles)(NewProjectDialog));
```

Do you have any idea of what might be happening?
I have stayed hours trying to solve this.
Thank you.

Comment: Seems some along in `NewProjectDialog` onProjectCreate is passed to an HTMLElement. You may want to check particularly elements where `props` is directly forwarded to `HTMLElement` or share a less simplified version of your component.

Comment: In `NewProjectDialog`  I only use the `onProjectCreate` only on that Button inside the Grid component and in mapDispatchToProps . Nowhere else. Though, being new to React I might not have understood correctly what you have asked.

Comment: If you need the component here is a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/tAKgwN7Y

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. If you see in line 101, there is `{...other}` which is forwarding the rest of the props (including `onProjectCreate`) to `Dialog` component. There is a good chance that `Dialog` does similar and the `HTMLElement` is being passed `onProjectCreate` as an attribute so that ReactDOM warns about it. You can destructure `onProjectCreate` from `props` before forwarding the rest.

Comment: It worked:Solution was just as you said to destructure this.props:

const {  onProjectCreate, ...other } = this.props;

Then I would just use inside the component:

<Button onClick={onProjectCreate}> Create </Button>

Thank you so much.